# Can I use Google sign-in to generate user-id for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-signin

On my site, many users log in with Google Sign-In. 
Can I use the `profile.getId()` Google ID that I obtain from Google Sign-In (or an ID token) as user-id in Google Analytics?

Or even more directly: My question is, does Google Analytics integrate with Google Sign-In to connect the sessions of one and the same authenticated user across all the devices they use to access my site?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **YES.**

Details: GA does coherence with G-sign-in. It keeps a track of the user log-ins which take place over your website. In a sense, to provide the analysis of the number of times people visit and number of log-ins taking place. So in order to take advantage of GA you ought to manually allow it the access.